# Null when parse XML document Android

Tags: java, android, xml

i'm parsing an xml document like this:

```
InputStream raw = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("pubs.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder= dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(raw);
        NodeList lista = doc.getElementsByTagName("name");
        for(int i =0; i < lista.getLength(); i++)
            titulos.add(lista.item(i).getNodeValue());
```

well, when i look into my final list (titulos) all is null, and i don't know why, cause it takes some time to parse the XML document :/ what i am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html), the node value of an element is always null.  Instead, you need to retrieve the text content of the element.  Does this work any better?

```
for(int i =0; i < lista.getLength(); i++)
     titulos.add(lista.item(i).getTextContent());
```